# shared_from_this() returns std::shared_ptr<const X>, not std::shared_ptr<X>

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, shared-ptr

OK, this one has me stumped. Clearly I've missed something, so I hope someone can tell me what it is.

I'm developing a C++17 library. I've written a custom tree data structure composed of `Node` objects and a custom iterator, `Node::iterator`, for traversing the tree. The iterator looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
class NodeIterator {
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer = std::shared_ptr<T>;
    using reference = T&;
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

    NodeIterator() = default;
    NodeIterator(pointer n);

    // Etc.
}
```

And later...

```
template class NodeIterator<Node>;
template class NodeIterator<const Node>;
```

When I add the standard iterator methods (`begin()`, `end()`, and the const equivalents) to a parent class `Tree`, I can control the initial value for the iterator. So I can say

```
Node::iterator Tree::begin() const {
    return Node::iterator(_root);
}
```

where `_root` is a `std::shared_ptr<Node>`. This works great.

However, not content to leave well enough alone, I want these iterator methods on the node itself. That way I can traverse a subtree from any node, eliminate the `Tree` class altogether, and just pass around `Node` objects.

I declare `Node` as

```
class Node : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Node> {
public:
    using iterator = NodeIterator<Node>;
    using const_iterator = NodeIterator<const Node>;

    iterator begin() const;
    iterator end() const;
    const_iterator cbegin() const;
    const_iterator cend() const;

    // Etc.
}
```

and define the iterator methods as

```
Node::iterator Node::begin() const {
    return Node::iterator(this->shared_from_this());
}

Node::iterator Node::end() const {
    return Node::iterator(nullptr);
}

Node::const_iterator Node::cbegin() const {
    return Node::const_iterator(this->shared_from_this());
}

Node::const_iterator Node::cend() const {
    return Node::const_iterator(nullptr);
}
```

The compiler then loudly complains about the `return` statement:

```
src/node.cc:79:9: error: no matching conversion for functional-style cast from
      'shared_ptr<const Node>' to 'Node::iterator' (aka 'NodeIterator<Node>')
        return Node::iterator(this->shared_from_this());
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

and later...

```
include/example.h:344:2: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known
      conversion from 'shared_ptr<const Node>' to 'shared_ptr<Node>' for
      1st argument
        NodeIterator(pointer n);
        ^
```

In another method, `Node::appendChild()`, I automatically set the parent node (`std::shared_ptr<Node>`) to `this->shared_from_this()`, and it works fine.

If I comment out `Node::begin()` and `Node::end()` and only use `cbegin()` and `cend()` in my loop, it also works fine.

What gives?

Comment: Presumably one of your member functions is `const` and the other is not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`shared_from_this` has const and non-const overloads. See [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this). Within your const `begin`, `this` is pointer to const and calls the const overload which returns a `shared_ptr` to const.

Comment: I updated my question to add some more detail around how I declare and define the iterator methods. Can you go into a bit more detail about what your suggested solution would be?

Comment: @MatthewRatzloff Have `begin() const` return a `const_iterator` and `begin()` (non-const) return an `iterator`, like they should.  Being able to modify a const object by iterating over it would be bad.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thanks! I mistakenly thought `cbegin()` and `cend()` *were* the constant equivalents (vector, list, map...). Didn't realize you were supposed to just overload `begin()` and `end()`. And my brain evidently warped over the const at the end of both of those...

Comment: `cbegin`/`cend` exist so you can readily get a const iterator from a non-const object without have to do an explicit const_cast.  Most of the time you just use begin/end which are overloaded to work on either const or non-const.